# Wait for the response from a PHP page before submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, wait

Before submitting a form, I want to validate the data by calling a PHP page, which returns an empty string if everything is okay and an error message if not. My current code works, but async: false is deprecated. I'm having trouble finding an alternative that works. Can you help me?

Thank you!

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    let idForm = $(this).attr("id");
    if(correspFormCtrl[idForm]) {
        let dataFormArray = $(this).serializeArray();
        let dataForm = dataFormArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
            acc[item.name] = item.value;
            return acc;
        }, {});
        let cible = $(this);
        let ok = false;
        
        
        
        $.ajax({
            url : "php/verifHtmlForm.php", 
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: { listeChamps: correspFormCtrl[idForm].champs, valeursForm: dataForm},
            success: function(data) {
                if(data) {
                    cible.find(".retourErreurForm").removeClass("invisible")[0].scrollIntoView({ block: 'start' });
                    cible.find(".infosErreurHtml").html(data);
                }
                else {
                    cible.find(".retourErreurForm").addClass("invisible");
                    ok = true;
                }
            },
            complete : function() {
                if(!ok) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have tried using a Promise, but i don't exactly know how to use this type of technology or if it's appropriate to use in this scenario.

Comment: Can't you verify on the client and then submit to the server verification that simply redirects to the final destination, or move the validation to the final destination code? There is no point in using AJAX if the page reloads anyway

Comment: I don't want the page to reload if the form isn't ok, I want to let the user change the values if they are not correct

Comment: Yes, so verify on the client until they get it right. Then ALSO verify it on the server but only submit ONCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async and await with a Promise to achieve
The validateForm function returns a Promise. The $.ajax call is wrapped in a Promise to make it easier to use with await.

```
$("form").on("submit", async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let idForm = $(this).attr("id");
    if (correspFormCtrl[idForm]) {
        let dataFormArray = $(this).serializeArray();
        let dataForm = dataFormArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
            acc[item.name] = item.value;
            return acc;
        }, {});

        try {
            let data = await validateForm(dataForm, correspFormCtrl[idForm].champs);

            let cible = $(this);

            if (data) {
                cible.find(".retourErreurForm").removeClass("invisible")[0].scrollIntoView({ block: 'start' });
                cible.find(".infosErreurHtml").html(data);
            } else {
                cible.find(".retourErreurForm").addClass("invisible");
                this.submit(); // Continue with the form submission
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
});

function validateForm(dataForm, champs) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/verifHtmlForm.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { listeChamps: champs, valeursForm: dataForm },
            success: function (data) {
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                reject(error);
            },
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The "don't submit" part works, but the submit part reloads the page without posting form's data :(

Comment: remove this line this.submit(); // Continue with the form submission and see if it works

Comment: Finally, by adding this line before the submit, it worked:
$('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', nameForm).attr('value', 1).appendTo('#' + idForm);
The submit() function doesn't include the form name (or the submit button name, I'm not sure which one is usually taken) unlike the "natural" post. This was causing an issue in my code.
Thank you very much for your help!